# why do not the same color html/css

Tags: html, css

Why the near button background color not the gray, but white. And how do to same gray like upper? Where I can found similar contact form to my made. Sorry for my bad English.

```css
.row1:before,
.row1:after{
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row1:after,{
  clear: both;
}
.row1 {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.Contact_form{
  width: 60%;
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}
._input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 1.38;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}
._input-long{
  height: 110px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
._input-1 {
  height: 40px;
}
._button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 23.2333333333%;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 57.53385%;
  background-color: #2979ff;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.Contact_text{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row1">
   <div class="Contact_text">
   <p>Palikyte mums =inut4</p>
   <hr></hr> 
   </div>
   <div class=".Contact_form"> 
    <input id="name" class="_input _input-1 js-name" name="J8s7 vardas" placeholder="J8s7 vardas" type="text">
    <input id="connection" class="_input _input-1 js-contact" name="mail&phone" placeholder="Tel. nr." type="text">
    <input class="_input-long _input" name="+inute" placeholder="asdasdsad" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="send" class="_button js-send_info">Si7sti =inut3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: To those of you voting to close, if it was unclear, how are there two answers that solve the problem?

Comment: Close-voters, the question isn't hugely unclear if you look past the unavoidable barrier that is the human language..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the gray is not behind the button at the bottom is due to the `float` property. Anytime you use floats you need to clear them, otherwise you have the chance for this to occur. The easy fix for you is to add "overflow:hidden;" to the `row1` class as you see below I have done.

```css
.row1:before,
.row1:after{
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row1:after,{
  clear: both;
}
.row1 {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow:hidden; /* NEW CODE*/
}
.Contact_form{
  width: 60%;
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}
._input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 1.38;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}
._input-long{
  height: 110px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
._input-1 {
  height: 40px;
}
._button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 23.2333333333%;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 57.53385%;
  background-color: #2979ff;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.Contact_text{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row1">
   <div class="Contact_text">
   <p>Palikyte mums =inut4</p>
   <hr></hr> 
   </div>
   <div class=".Contact_form"> 
    <input id="name" class="_input _input-1 js-name" name="J8s7 vardas" placeholder="J8s7 vardas" type="text">
    <input id="connection" class="_input _input-1 js-contact" name="mail&phone" placeholder="Tel. nr." type="text">
    <input class="_input-long _input" name="+inute" placeholder="asdasdsad" type="text">
    <button type="submit" id="send" class="_button js-send_info">Si7sti =inut3</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: *'Anytime you use floats you need to clear them'* is a little misleading. If we ***always*** had to clear floats there would be no point in having them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<button>` is floated, taking it out of the normal page flow. Its parent, `.Contact_form` doesn't stretch to accommodate it anymore. You can use the `overflow` style to clear any floats.

Also the `class` attribute takes classes without the period (`.`).

```css
.row1:before,
.row1:after{
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.row1:after,{
  clear: both;
}
.row1 {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.Contact_form{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
  float: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
}
._input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  line-height: 1.38;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px;
}
._input-long{
  height: 110px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
._input-1 {
  height: 40px;
}
._button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 23.2333333333%;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 57.53385%;
  background-color: #2979ff;
  line-height: 1.38;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.Contact_text{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 10%;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row1">
        <div class="Contact_text">
            <p>Palikyte mums =inut4</p>
            <hr></hr> 
        </div>
        <div class="Contact_form"> 
            <input id="name" class="_input _input-1 js-name" name="J8s7 vardas" placeholder="J8s7 vardas" type="text">
            <input id="connection" class="_input _input-1 js-contact" name="mail&phone" placeholder="Tel. nr." type="text">
            <input class="_input-long _input" name="+inute" placeholder="asdasdsad" type="text">
            <button type="submit" id="send" class="_button js-send_info">Si7sti =inut3</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand, but after running the snippet, I assume you either want the entire page background in grey, or you want the blue button in grey to match the top section.

http://jsfiddle.net/6ruzjvd5/

```
<input class="_input _input-1 js-name" type="submit" id="send" value="Si7sti =inut3">
```

A little problem with class placement if I'm correct